# scrape to excel file

Tags: c#, csv, web-scraping

I am working on a program to get proxylists from the web to a datagridview and then add an option to export the data to csv.
I am really a noob and want to know the way of doing so without connecting to a SQL DB. I just want it to get the data (done this already), show it in columns locally and export to csv as an option.
I heard it can be done somehow with LINQ.
Can I see an example? I just can't seem to find anything out on the web..

Also exporting to csv would help..

Thanks!

Comment: You said, "get proxylists from the web".  If this means your getting the list off another website, you'll need to research web scraping to download the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this library out, worked like a charm for me. Has some examples on there for you. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

One of my first projects as a programmer was something along these lines, so GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

At work we use the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start.html) open source library for CSV manipulation. It is super easy to use and extremely quick to develop against with a small learning curve (which is really important when using 3rd party libraries).